# Confused about the difference between these two derivatives

Tags: calculus

So for a function $f(x) = e^{\sin(x^2)}$, you're supposed to apply the chain rule to it to get $e^{\sin(x^2)}(\cos(x^2))(2x)$.

But for a function $f(x) = 5^{\cos(x)}$, you apply the $a^x(\ln(a))$ rule, to get $5^{\cos(x)}\ln(5)(-\sin(x))$??

I'm confused, cause $5$ and $e$ are both numbers with a trig function as its exponent, why do we treat them differently?

Comment: Do you know what $\ln(e)$ is?

Comment: It's 1, correct?

Answer (score 3):

You don't treat them differently. In fact, you have
$$ \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} a^x = a^x\ln(a),$$
for any $a > 0.$ In particular, when $a=e$, you land back in the usual derivative of the exponential:
$$ \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} e^x = e^x\ln(e) = e^x,$$
since $\ln (e) = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

For $a>0$ and $x\in \Bbb R$,

$$5^{\cos(x)}=e^{\cos(x)\ln(5)}=e^{u(x)}$$

the derivative is

$$u'(x)e^{u(x)}=-\ln(5)\sin(x)e^{\cos(x)\ln(5)}$$